# Parse iOS SDK: Calling Cloud Functions From Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, cloud

**Scenario**
I have these two Cloud Functions that I want to use in my application. They check for the online status of the user and I want to set a boolean key "isOnline" for each user to YES if the user is online and to NO if they are not.

```
var moment = require("moment");

Parse.Cloud.define("registerActivity", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    user.set("lastActive", new Date());
    user.save().then(function (user) {
        response.success();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
    });
});

Parse.Cloud.define("getOnlineUsers", function(request, response) {
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var activeSince = moment().subtract("minutes", 2).toDate();
    userQuery.greaterThan("lastActive", activeSince);
    userQuery.find().then(function (users) {
        response.success(users);
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

**Problem**
I am not the best with Javascript, and because of that I need some help getting my head around what is happening/what I'm supposed to do.

**Questions**
**1**) When do I call "registerActivity" and "getOnlineUsers" inside my Xcode project?

**2**) Is "response.success(users)" just an array of PFUser Objects?

**3**) If "2)" is true, then how do I set the bool key "isOnline" for all of the users in the "response.success(users)" to YES if they are in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You would call these functions when you want to get the online users. The code for calling these would be:

   ```
   [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"registerActivity" withParameters:@{@"user": Put objectId for user here}                             
   block:^(NSString *response, NSError *error) {
                                       if (!error) {

                                       }
                                   }];

   [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getOnlineUsers" withParameters:@{} 
   block:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) { 
   if (!error) 
   {

   } }];
   ```
2. Yes, I believe it would just be an array of PFUser objects, I would run this just to make sure, though.
3. Once you get the response from "getOnlineUsers" you should probably send it back up to another cloud code function that uses the master key (`Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();`) to access/change user objects, and change the "isOnline" field to YES.

Comment: Hey Jacob thanks so much for your answer. If you could clarify this one thing for me I appreciate it because no one explained this to me - So, is NSArray *users (in your completion block code above) the same thing as response.success(users) in the cloud function?

Comment: Also if you could help me out with this too. **Where** in my Xcode project do I call "registerActivity" and "getOnlineUsers"? Do I call "registerActivity" in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method? Do I call "getOnlineUsers" every time I set a "onlineLabel" to either Online or Offline?

Comment: Tom, no problem. Yes, they are basically the same. When you call response.success(users), you are sending back the array of user objects to the block, and it becomes NSArray *users. As for your second question, I'm a little confused. I'm guessing the point of these functions is to get a list of online users and most likely display it to the user in the app. If you want this to happen when the app launches, then I would put it in the code for your first view controller, otherwise, I would put it anywhere you want to get a list of online users. If I'm understand this wrong, please let me know.

Comment: So calling a parse function.. the function will not return a raw JSON but a PFObject?

Comment: @VanDuTran It depends what you want to return, you can pick.

Comment: @Jacob what if the JSON contains two objects of distinct type/class. Will it still be possible to have them as PFObjects?

Comment: @VanDuTran I believe this is possible, yes. You cannot store PFObjects in NSUserDefaults, though.

Comment: @Jacob thanks! Can you share any hints you have regarding how to convert two objects from distinct class to corresponding PFObjects?

Comment: @VanDuTran Well, it depends on the fields of your PFObject. I would just create a new PFObject with the desired fields, set them to the desired values, and save.