# Call Parse Cloud Function for current user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to run some Cloud Functions in Parse, following along with a question I found here on Stackoverflow ([Parse iOS SDK: Calling Cloud Functions From Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873261/parse-ios-sdk-calling-cloud-functions-from-xcode)). Here are the functions I'd like to call within my app:

```
var moment = require("moment");

Parse.Cloud.define("registerActivity", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    user.set("lastActive", new Date());
    user.save().then(function (user) {
        response.success();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.error(error);
    });
});

Parse.Cloud.define("getOnlineUsers", function(request, response) {
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var activeSince = moment().subtract("minutes", 2).toDate();
    userQuery.greaterThan("lastActive", activeSince);
    userQuery.find().then(function (users) {
        response.success(users);
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

I'd like to call the registerActivity function within a viewDidLoad within one of my view controllers. Here's what I have so far. I need some help completing the function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("registerActivity", withParameters: currentUser){
            if (!error){

            }
        }

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }
```

I get an error on the "PFCloud" line that states: `PFUser is not identical to [NSOBject:Anyobject]`. How can I call this registerActivity function for the current user?

Thanks!

**Update**

Updated function call in viewDidLoad to:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("registerActivty", withParameters: nil, block: nil)
```

Which leads to an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
```

**LAST UPDATE:**
This to solved the problem:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("registerActivity", withParameters: [:], target: nil, selector: "block:")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to give `currentUser` if it is already logged in. In server side `request.user` will be already set to the logged in user that is making the request. In this case, you can call the cloud function with a parameter of empty dictionary.

On the other hand, the error you are getting is because PFUser object can't be passed to a cloud function. You can pass the user id as `["id": currentUser.objectId]`. Then in the server, you can access it as `request.params.id` to get the user by `id`. This is in case you want to call the cloud function for any user (even it is not logged in).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed my function call to  `PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("registerActivty", withParameters: nil, block: nil)` but now I get an exception when I run the app. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'` Am I getting this because I need to pass in params.id instead of nil?

Comment: You need to pass an empty dictionary instead of nil. In objective-c it would be `@{}`